# Unique constraint in Grails

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm

Assuming i have the following grail domain entities:

```
class A { ... }

class B { ... }
```

In a third entity i have a one to many relationship as follows:

```
class C {
    static belongsTo = [a: A, b: B]

    static constraints {
        a unique: 'b'
    }
}
```

Is it possible in grails to define a unique relationship based on both properties (`a` and `b`) in class `C`, so no two `C` instances may be created having the same combination of `a` and `b`?

EDIT: My test case has as follows:

```
void testCompositeUniqueConstraint() {
    A a = // ...
    B b = // ...
    C existing = // ...
    existing.a = a
    existing.b = b
    mockForConstraintsTests(C, [existing])

    C c = // ...
    c.a = a
    c.b = b

    assertFalse c.validate()
}
```

On my test class i have included the `@Mock([A, B])` annotation. I would expect this test to fail but it passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be

```
static constraints = {
   a unique: 'b'
}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html

Comment: Thad doesn't seem to work. In my test i can save two different instances of C with the same A and B instances. I've already read this guide but i haven't managed to make this work.

Comment: I have updated my question including my test case plus additional information. Thanx.